# Trigger is re-triggered by internal select on same table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm having this very strange issue that took me hours just to discover. My code worked perfectly during test with static `@Start` and `@End` variables defined, but within the trigger, these are being updated unexpectedly and the cause is the line in the first block of code that inserts values into `@tbl`.

I suspect this must be because I am selecting values from the very same table the trigger is for. However, since this is only a `select` and not an `update` I would have never expected this behavior.

I need to accomplish the following: When a task is updated, I need to check all other tasks for the Chore to see if they are completed and if so, perform inner logic.

I would deeply appreciate some insight here. I've been stuck on this for days now. :(

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ut_Task_Update_PC ON tblTasks
AFTER UPDATE
AS
--Global Vars
declare @Start int, @End int, @ChoreID int
set @ChoreID = (select ChoreID from inserted)
set @Start  = (select PC from inserted) -- PC = PercentComplete
set @End    = (select PC from deleted)
print('1A: Start = '+cast(@Start as varchar(12))+', End = '+cast(@End as varchar(12)))
--Logic
if (@Start=100) and (@End=100) begin
    print('Do nothing: Case 1.')
end else if (@Start=100) and (@End<100) begin
    print('Do nothing: Case 2.')
end else if (@Start>0) and (@End<100) begin
    print('Do nothing: Case 3.')
end else begin
    declare @tbl table (PC int)
    print('2A: Start = '+cast(@Start as varchar(12))+', End = '+cast(@End as varchar(12)))
    --PROBLEM HERE: inserting explicit value = ok; inserting from same table
    --  referenced by trigger somehow triggers another update but only once.
    --insert @tbl values (1)
    insert @tbl select isnull(PC,0) as [PC] from tblTasks
        where ChoreID = @ChoreID and IsCancelled = 0
    print('2B: Start = '+cast(@Start as varchar(12))+', End = '+cast(@End as varchar(12)))
    if not exists (select null from @tbl where PC = 0)
        and (select count(*) from @tbl) > 0 begin --DESIRED CASE
        --Never reached
    end
end
```

If the problem is not immediate obvious, you might try the below code for testing.

```sql
--Testing: use this sample table and add the above trigger
-- I trimmed away a LOT of extraneous code, but this should
-- reflect the same problems I'm having
CREATE TABLE tblTask(
    TaskID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ChoreID int NOT NULL,
    PC int,
    IsCancelled bit
)
```

Comment: YOur trigger is very bad. It assumes that inserted and deleted will only have one value. It will not work correctly inteh case of mulitple record updates. This needs to be completely rewritten to avoid using scalar variables to hold hold values from inserted.

Comment: And you should never use a print statement in a trigger

Comment: For futre refernce trigger in SQL Server run in sets not row by row, so it will trigger once for each update.

Comment: @HLGEM: On the GUI I only ever update one Task at a time, so that should be fine in this case, as for using `print`, why not? What should I use instead? It was only temporary for testing anyway.

Comment: Databases are never affected only by the GUI. You should not even be thinking about the GUI whe you write a trigger.  It is irresponsible  to assume that only one record will be changed. Triggers by definition must be able to handle updates from anywhere including set-based updates where possibly you change an entire client's data or insert historical data for a new client or delete all of an old client's data. Print is useless in a trigger. Triggers need to run as fast as possible and using print statments will slow them down.

Comment: @HLGEM It's either print or select, I know no other way to debug, and I don't WANT set updates. This table should ONLY be updating one record at a time. I'm just trying to hack this and need a quick fix, I don't need to be preached at about what is proper at this moment. I've got too much to do. We each have to make judgement calls in the interest of timely responses for our business whether we like it or not. Naturally I would love to ALWAYS adhere to best practices, but it is absolutely naive to think this is always possible. :(